# Retrieve dataset calculated fields quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to fetch dataset description using aws quicksight describe-data-set
this returns the columns and the calculated fields added on analyses, but not the calculated fields added in the dataset level (they are presented like regular fields without giving info on calculation)

[**further clarification**: there are two ways to add calculated fields in quicksight: one is directly on the dataset and the second one is on an analysis based on the datset, and my case is that "*describe-data-set*" shows only those from the second option presented]

aws quicksight describe-data-set
expecting to get all  calculated fields

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.